# Next.js Auth: Self-Hosted vs Third Part Provider

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm developing a webapp with Next.js and I am at a point where I need to decide on an authentication strategy. My options seem to boil down to two main categories:

- **Self-Hosted Authentication:** using libraries like [Auth.js](https://authjs.dev/) or [Lucia Auth](https://lucia-auth.com/) that are hosted on the same server.
- **Third-Party Authentication Services:** utilizing services like [Supabase](https://supabase.com/) or [Clerk](https://clerk.com/).

I’m wondering about the benefits of choosing one over the other.

Ideally, I prefer authentication hosted on the same server so I don’t need to rely on third-party services, but I’m concerned there might be problems I’m not aware of.

*Last question, if I need a simple authentication system using only email and password, implemented with JWT (without the need for providers like Google or Github), can I implement it? Or is it a bad idea?*

Thanks!